# Python: how to use each line at a time from array in requests

Tags: python, arrays, python-requests

How to use each line at a time from an array further in requests:

The code:

```
x = ['param1', 'param2']
r = requests.get('http://somesite.com/?p='.format(x))
```

"https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp" - Not working - only takes the last word from array

It works only for PRINT

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

Comment: Not working, only takes the last word from array

Comment: I can guarantee you it will work if you use it with some thought.

Comment: It only works for PRINT. But in the request IT only takes the last word from array

Comment: First of all, your usage of format is incorrect because you don't show where to insert the formatted variable. 2nd, make sure you use the actual variable from loop and not the whole list. (HINT: `x` in your example is `fruits` in the w3 example)

Answer (score 1):

Use a python `for` loop like this:

```
inputs = ["p1", "p2"]
result = []
for elem in inputs:
  result.append(requests.get(f'http://somesite.com/?p={elem}'))
print(result)
```

This should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ['param1', 'param2']

for z in x
    r = requests.get('http://somesite.com/?p='.format(x))
    print(r)
```

`for z in x` is a `for` loop.

z could be anything, it's a placeholder for "one object in my array".

Your array has two items `param1` and `param2` so this will do whatever is inside that loop, in this case `print` them both once.

Comment: This answer is not correct, `r` will be overwritten!

Comment: OP hasn't said he wants or doesn't want that.

Comment: True, but they do store the response in `r` so presumably it is needed elsewhere, or they wouldn't do that.

Comment: He added print, and it's for a tutorial so I expect he's not looking for much. And this answer would indeed print out both array objects.

Comment: Now it would (: Thanks for the efffort and prompt replies (:

Comment: I dont want to print them, i want X from requests to load each word from array

Comment: You want all the words from websites in the array? And what do you mean by "load"?

Comment: I want all the words from array to be executare each at a time in the request

Comment: What do you mean by executing? Words can't execute by themselves, there is nothing to "run".

Comment: This is just a part from the script. I just need the words from array to be loaded each time in the requests. C'mon there are 2 lines posted...the words and the request where i need the words to be loaded

Comment: That doesn't make any sense that's the issue. People aren't going to help you if you talk to them link that. Upload the full script and we might be able to help you.